# jquery Show and Hide the picture by number of question?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey I have 10 ten image in a div(name is background).. and display properties is none..

I want to  show by questions number..   I mean Question=1 img1.hide(),img2.show() Question=2 img2.hide(); img3.show ............ question 10  img9.hide() img10.show

my function name is resim()  and it callback from Button click

function resim(question)  This is wrong right :) Actually this is wrong.. it doesn't work :))

```
var i=0;
while (i<3)
{
    if (question==i)
    {
        $("#background img").eq(i-1).hide();
        $("#background img").eq(i).show();
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

but I cant do the function... How must it be? Sorry about my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `div#background` contains all your `img` tags and `div#background` is set to `display:none;` then even if you set the images to show, they won't display because their parent element is set not to display.

You'll have to set the `div#background` to show and the individual `img` tags to hide and show the individual images as needed.

An alternate function you may want use could look like this:

```
function resim(question)
{
    $("#background img").hide();
    $("#background img:eq("+question+")").show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Question 1 you want to show the first image and so on?
question parameter is the Number of the question?
first hide all images, then show the image (question number minus 1 - index 0 based).

```
function resim(question) {
    // hide all
    $("#background img").hide();
    // show by Num
    $("#background img").eq(question-1).show();
}
```

Be sure the div background has display: block and not none.